# can not access to server with ingress-nginx with kubernetes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

i want to access to the server with this route but not worked . `https://ticketing.dev/api/user/currentuser`

i craete in the root folder `skaffold.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta11
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: kia9372/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

and i crate a folder by name `infra` and in that i create a folder by name `k8s` . in this folder i create two file :

**A :** `auth-depl.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: kia9372/auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

**B :** `ingress-srv.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ticketing.dev
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/user/?(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: auth-srv
            port:
              number: 4000
```

and into the `/etc/hosts` i writeing this :

```
 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters


127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mr-programmer
127.0.1.1   ticketing.dev
```

but now i have a problem . when i want to go in this route `https://ticketing.dev/api/user/currentuser` it not show my any things . i test the server seprate the kubernetes by this `https://localhost:4000/api/user/currentuser` and it works .

**whats the prblem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: Are you using minikube ??

Comment: @DebasisDas yes i using minikube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Solution` :

1. Go to your terminal
2. Enter `minikube ip` - you will get minikube ip ( examle : 172.17.0.2)
3. `Edit /etc/hosts` :

change `127.0.1.1   ticketing.dev` to
`172.17.0.2 (minikube ip)   ticketing.dev`

You can not write here local ip address(127.0.1.1), you should write here minikube ip address(172.17.0.2), because you are using minikube.